# android - Sometimes get '502 Bad Gateway' in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I got '502 Bad Gateway' from WebViewClient' onReceivedHttpError, and then there is just one message: "the specified cgi application encountered an error and the server terminated the process." showing in WebView without any content.

I got this issue after re-opened the WebView many times, but the link work fine on PC browser. When I re-install the application, it shown normal content in the first few times.

I tried to change WebSettings below, but still not work.

```java
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private void settingWebView() {
        final WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

        // js
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // ui control
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);

        // cache
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);

        // others
        settings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);

        // web view
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.setInitialScale(100);

        // client
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
                super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
                Log.e(TAG, "onReceivedHttpError: " + errorResponse.getStatusCode());
                Log.e(TAG, "onReceivedHttpError: " + errorResponse.getReasonPhrase());
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl(DevelopUtil.TACTICS_WEB_VIEW);
    }
```

Do anybody knows what is the problem ? 
Is it server error or my WebView setting error ?

Answer (score 0):

try this it worked for me

```
WebViewClient webClient = new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFormResubmission(WebView view, Message dontResend,
                                           Message resend) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onFormResubmission(view, dontResend, resend);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
                if (url.contains("purchasehistory.html")) {
                   // mURLNavigation.onURLNavigation(3);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }
        };
```